# Ошибка: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'

Tags: asp.net

Создаю небольшую форму, к полям формы подключены валидаторы.
Библиотека jQuery к проекту у меня подключена.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

но когда запускаю отладку проекта, то выдается ошибка

[image: ошибка снрвера в приложении]

На `stackoverflow` есть описание решения такой проблемы [Unobtrusive Validation with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452109/asp-net-2012-unobtrusive-validation-with-jquery).
Но не могу разобраться, как это прописать в файле Global.asax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение нашлось.
В файле Global.asax в Application_Start надо было прописать

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery",
        new ScriptResourceDefinition
        {
            Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js",
            DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js",
            CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js",
            CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
        });
}
```